# dhcpcd not calling wpa_supplicant on yocto image

Tags: yocto

### Context

I'm currently trying to bake a yocto image for the Raspberry Pi 3B and I want it to connect automatically to Wifi.

This is the repo: https://github.com/retpolanne/raspberry-pi-image-ansible

For configuring wpa_supplicant, I created this .bbappend for wpa_supplicant and it successfully adds my wpa config to /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf. https://github.com/retpolanne/raspberry-pi-image-ansible/blob/master/rpi-build/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant_2.10.bbappend

My /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1
country=BR

network={
    ssid="myssid"
    psk=mypsk
}
```

My build also bakes dhcpcd.

### Issue

As far as I understand, dhcpcd should start up wpa_supplicant via a hook. This doc [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dhcpcd) tells me that, in order to make dhcpcd automatically start wpa_supplicant, I need to `ln -s /usr/share/dhcpcd/hooks/10-wpa_supplicant /usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/`. The `10-wpa_supplicant` file exists, however the `/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks` doesn't. I tried creating it but wpa_supplicant still doesn't start.

wpa_supplicant systemd service is disabled by default, but if I enable it it get started but not by dhcpcd.

### More context

I found that the [dhcpcd-run-hooks script](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.html) is located at `/usr/libexec/dhcpcd-run-hooks` for some reason and it has these hook addresses:

```
# We source each script into this one so that scripts run earlier can
# remove variables from the environment so later scripts don't see them.
# Thus, the user can create their dhcpcd.enter/exit-hook script to configure
# /etc/resolv.conf how they want and stop the system scripts ever updating it.
for hook in \                                
        /etc/dhcpcd.enter-hook \                                       
        /usr/libexec/dhcpcd-hooks/* \
        /etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook        
do
```

Linking to the libexec directory:

```
ln -s /usr/share/dhcpcd/hooks/10-wpa_supplicant /usr/libexec/dhcpcd-hooks/
```

Aaaand wpa_supplicant started!

### TL;DR

How do I make wpa_supplicant be started by dhcpcd through systemd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems that the dhcpcd recipe on bitbake put these hooks under /usr/libexec/dhcpcd-hooks.

The solution is to add a bbappend to dhcpcd that runs do_install:append and links the hook to the correct directory.

Example here: https://github.com/retpolanne/raspberry-pi-image-ansible/commit/61e57e9a2329d23e6d3e593e27ae593185e0f734